# Deleting SDL2 window while preserving the GL context

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

Is it possible, in SDL2, to destroy a window while preserving the GL context that was made for it?

I'm trying to allow the user to toggle border-less window mode, which as far as I can tell, requires recreating the window. It would be ideal if I didn't have to reload all of the GL resources due to having to create a new GL context.

Can I just destroy the window and make the existing GL context the current context for the new window, or does destroying the window destroy/invalidate the OpenGL context which was created for it? I can only find documentation for sharing the context, but not for recycling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SDL_SetWindowBordered(SDL_Window*, SDL_bool);`

I don't know about the answer to your question though.

Comment: Oh, neat, thanks! I think that suffices as far as an answer. Apparently resizing an SDL window that's in full-screen mode may invalidate all GL assets anyway (possibly not in newer versions of SDL2), so I don't think a solution my question would serve me very well. I'm not sure what I was searching for that I didn't find this function.

Comment: @Jengerer Another thing to note, the popular thing to do today is to have the window never go 'fullscreen', but just become borderless and the size of the monitor. It's a lot easier to work with that way.

Comment: Thanks, I did know of that trick. From what I remember, though, it has a few performance hits from not being fullscreen, so ultimately I think the best choice is to allow the user to toggle fullscreen behaviour (as many newer games do already).